# How would you integrate a TCP server implementation like Quickfixj into Spring-Integration project?

Tags: java, spring-integration, quickfixj

I'm wanting to implement Quickfixj with all its built in functionality into a project that uses Spring-Integration. I had thought that I could wrap this library as one of Spring-Integration's endpoint objects. However, I'm struggling to understand whether I should use a channel adapter or a gateway or if I'm supposed to be using something else. How would I have Quickfixj or any other type server setup to work on its own and pass messages into a channel?

Quickfixj already provides all of the functionality I need for listening to a TCP port, parsing and validating messages, etc. I'm only needing to output the received message to a larger system through a channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be straightforward, Spring Integration provides the [Messaging Gateway](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#gateway) to integrate from regular Java code with an integration flow.

Simply provide an interface and the framework will create the implementation.

When you receive a QuickFixJ message, simply call the gateway.

You may want to map a QuickFixJ message to a `spring-messaging` `Message<?>` (payload, headers), or you can simply send the QuickFixJ message as the payload of the `Message<?>` - it really depends on your requirements.